# Can a function that is equal to infinity at one or more points be Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

I suspect that it can, since a function is Riemann integrable when the set of discontinuities over its domain of definition is measure zero.  Is this a reasonable way of approaching the problem?

Comment: What is the codomain of your function?

Comment: Being "equal to infinity" has no meaning. Being unbounded in an interval does, and such a function is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Eckhard the co-domain is R

Comment: @user72279: Do you see that in light of your last comment your question doesn't really make sense?  Infinity is not a real number, so if the codomain of your function is $\mathbb{R}$ (as it should be in the study of Riemann integration!) your function cannot be "equal to infinity at one or more points".

Answer (score 2):

No, the Lebesgue criterion for Riemann integrabiility says the function has to be bounded in addition to being continuous almost everywhere.  If $f(p) = \infty$ and $p$ happens to be  one of the points at which you evaluate $f$ in a Riemann sum, that Riemann sum will be infinite.

Comment: Is it not possible to decide not to pick those points if there are only countably many of them?

Comment: @user72279: then you are  _not_ using Riemann integration.

Comment: @willieWong I think I understand, so it is okay to have countably many discontinuous points as long as they ensure the function is still bounded as we cannot choose the points we are picking?

Comment: Yes, a bounded function with countably many discontinuities is OK.